# Reactjs - How to load and map data in reactjs material table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mapping, loaddata

How to load and map data in reactjs material [Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#tables). I'm passing an object to child component via `Cards` component. when console log I can receive object from parent but it is throwing `failed to compile` error. Can anyone let me know where I made mistake?

**Card.tsx**

```
function createData(type: any, description: any, volume: any) {
  return { type, description, volume };
}

class Card extends Component {
 constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    const rows = props.value.cargo;
    rows.map((data: any) => {
      createData(data.type, data.description, data.volume);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card className="Card">
        <CardContent className="Card-Content">
              <Table className="Card-Content__Table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>type</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>description</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>volume</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {rows.map(row => (
                    <TableRow key={row.volume}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {row.type}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.description}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.volume}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

**Cards.tsx**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.card.map((card: any) => (
          <Card key={card.id} value={card} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const rows` you defined in the constructor isn't accessible from `render()`. It is only accessible within the constructor function. If you wanted to create a parameter that would be accessible within the whole class, you could create it like this:

```
this.rows = props.value.cargo;
```

And then access it using `this.rows` instead of just `rows`.

For this example, though, that serves no purpose and would give you other problems in the future with the props not updating correctly between renders.

You should use `this.props.value.cargo.map` instead of `rows.map` in `render()`. You can also create another `const rows` inside of `render()`, if you wanna make it cleaner. It's OK that they both have the same name, since they are in different scopes.